# If shorthand question

Tags: apex

I'm getting the 'Expression cannot be assigned' error. 
I can use the regular 'IF' statement but I'm just curious why this won't work.

```
public static void sendEmail(Group_Name__c g, Boolean b){
    Id emailTempID;
    b ? emailTempId = [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='New_Intercept_Group'].id : emailTempId = [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='Old_Intercept_Group'].id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You notation is wrong. It should be

> condition ? expr1 : expr2

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```
public static void sendEmail(Group_Name__c g, Boolean b){
    Id emailTempID;
    emailTempId  = b ? [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='New_Intercept_Group'].id : [select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName='Old_Intercept_Group'].id;
}
```

Also note Mark's comments below:

> additionally, to be safe you must make sure you've always got an
>   EmailTemplate record returned by the query or the .id at the end of
>   the statement will throw an exception

Comment: additionally, to be safe you must make sure you've always got an `EmailTemplate` record returned by the query or the `.id` at the end of the statement will throw an exception.